# What does "вот уже" mean?

Tags: перевод

What does the phrase "вот уже" mean? For example, "Вот уже я знаю".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Уже** = already; **вот** is some analogue to *here*, but it may be omitted in the translation.

*Вот уже* means that *something has already happened* or *approaching*.

> И *вот уже* трещат морозы
>   И серебрятся средь полей...
>   (Читатель ждёт уж рифмы розы;
>   На, вот возьми её скорей!)

Another example:

> *Вот уж* снег последний в поле тает,
>   Теплый пар восходит от земли,
>   И кувшинчик синий расцветает,
>   И зовут друг друга журавли.

Thus *Вот уже я знаю* is simply another way (albeit, a little mannered one) of saying *Now I know*, unless said in a purely sarcastic tone meaning *Damned if I know*.

Answer (score 2):

It's like an invitation to have a look at the way the things have changed by the moment: '**as you can see now**', etc. In your example: *It came to the fact even I know that*.

```
Вот уже и пенсионера от смартфона не оттащишь - настолько они стали доступны.
```